# Possible to get arguments from an async function after it has run

Tags: python, exception, arguments, python-asyncio, coroutine

I'm having this case where I need to get from the coroutine about which task failed.

I'm using `asyncio.wait` and when a task fails with an exception, I cannot tell which arguments caused the task to fail.

I tried to read the coro cr_frame but it seems after the coro runs, the cr_frame returns `None`

I tried other things too like trying to edit the coro Class and trying to put a `attribute`

`coro.__mydata = data` but it seems that i cannot add attributes dynamically on the coro (maybe its a limitation on python, don't know)

Here's some code

```py
async def main():
    """
    Basically this function send messages to an api
    The class takes things like channelID, userID etc

    Sometimes channelID, userID are wrong and the task would return an exception
    """
    resp = await asyncio.wait(self._queue_send_task)

    for r in resp[0]:
        try:
            sent = r.result()
        except:
            ## Exception because of wrong args, I need the args to act upon them
            coro = r.get_coro()

            coro.cr_frame ## Returns none, normally this would return a frame if I were to call it before the coro start
```

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include a small and runnable example that demonstrates the issue? (The exception can be synthetic, e.g. raised by 1/0) That will help us give you the best approach for your particular situation.

Comment: @user4815162342 will be kinda hard to emulate since the full function is part of a library and quite big but I will try to simulate a case

Comment: You don't have to emulate everything, just how you are calling `wait` and how you are accessing the results. It's not immediately obvious why you'd need to tell which arguments caused the task to fall, or what that even means, precisely.

Comment: @user4815162342 I added some code

Comment: A minimal example should be **runnable**, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for details. Also, the code you posted includes your attempts to fix the problem (by accessing `cr_frame`) instead of showing what the original problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The asyncio API and best practices have changed a bit. If you schedule your coroutines/futures with `asyncio.create_task()` you'll get task objects back from `asyncio.wait()`. These task objects can get you a workable frame and you can recover the arguments from there.

```
# schedule multiple instances of `my_awaitable` to run asynchronously on the event loop.
tasks = [asyncio.create_task(my_awaitable(fn_arg)) for fn_arg in args]

# wait for them to finish.
done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks)

for task in done:
    # our task crashed with an exception. :(
    if exc := task.exception():
        logger.exception("Always log your errors!", exc_info=exc)
        if stack := task.get_stack():
            # get fn_arg from the first frame in the stack and do something with it.
            fn_arg = stack[0].f_locals.get("fn_arg")

    # do something with the result of the finished task
    else:
        retval = task.result()
```